# Internal server error on nginx with subdomains that do not exist

Tags: nginx

I want to redirect all traffic from subdomains that do not exist to the main domain. Currently I get a internal server error when trying to access a subdomain that do not exist.

**Do not exist:**

```
sub1.domain.com --> domain.com
sub2.domain.com --> domain.com
```

How can I do it with a wildcard setup?

Comment: [This document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

We need to send the request to a default server if a server block is not found, so we can make domain.com server block as default_server

1- put domain.com server block at the top and rest of the subdomains server block afterwards.

or

2- set domain.com server block explicitly as default_server

More [read](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html)